# The square of 1514

Tags: riddle

> I am the square of 1514,
>
> but actually, I'm just the square of 4.
>
> I possess a property,
>
> where women could be burned for in my time

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am the square of 1514,

> This is a magic square (more specifically, Dürer's magic square).

but actually, I'm just the square of 4.

> Such a magic square consists of $4 \times 4$ elements.

I possess a property,

where women could be burned for in my time

> Women who were accused of magic were burned during these ages.

Comment: I'm guessing 1514 refers to the year of discovery/publication? Would be nice to include this in the answer for completeness